# Why is this Javascript Function being skipped without throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute this function:

```
function GetFoo(){
    console.log('start GetFoo');
    var obj = {};
    obj.FOO = getCookie("FOO");
    console.log(obj);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webUrl + "/GetFooOnStuff",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response.d);
            var foos = JSON.parse(response.d);
            for(i in foos){
               // do do stuff with this data
            }
        },
        failure: function(response){
            console.log(response.d);
        },
        error: function(error) { 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

inside a jquery event like so:

```
$(function(){ 
    OtherFunction();
    GetFoo(); 
    AnotherFunction();
});
```

However, the GetFoo function seemingly doesn't run.
The 'OtherFunction' and 'AnotherFunction' run fine and give expected results, but the 'GetFoo' doesn't even log the first 'start getFoo' statement or any errors. It just simply doesn't execute.

Is there something completely obvious that I'm just overlooking?

Comment: Provided as is, there's no reason this code doesn't execute. I think we'd need more than that, how exactly did you implement it, where is this function written (in another .js file, etc?) Although if the file was not found, the function would not be defined, so you would get an error `GetFoo is not defined`.... so, hard to tell until we have more context, I think.

Comment: Try execute the function GetFoo() manually in the browser console, maybe when the method calls the function, it does not exists in the client side yet.

Comment: @JeremyThille I managed to solve the problem. Running the function in console did not do anything and after investigating the file, i found that another function was declared with the same name and was being executed over the one i intended. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error was found. A function with the exact same name but different statements was being called in the same file. 
It was simply poor function naming on my part.